# GObject g_type_init and g_object_new take hundres of milliseconds

Tags: c, performance, glib, gobject

We are using Apache Thrift in an Apache httpd module to inject data from another service into the request. That works fine except some strange performance problems that seem to stem from gobject.

Initialization of the type system and/or the first object takes normally <1ms, but sometimes there is a batch os requests that take much longer (like >100ms).

In the child_init-Handler, the g_type_init() is called to initialize the type system. When the request is read, the objects are created with g_object_new (around 6).

Time of object init is measured with `gettimeofday` to get the elapsed time for the user. It looks like this:

```
VhostResult *result = NULL;
struct timeval  tv1, tv2;
gettimeofday(&tv1, NULL);
result = g_object_new (TYPE_VHOST_RESULT, NULL);
gettimeofday(&tv2, NULL);
```

This problem only occurs in batches. All object inits are under <1ms for a few minutes and then there are ~10 requests in the same second that take 500ms to create the first object, all finishing at the same time.

Please not that the processes are always destroyed after the request so it is *always* a fresh forked process, which means no memory leaks.

**Edit**: As suggested, I added measurement with `clock()` in addition to wall time and it reports 0 for the measured code block.

**Edit 2**: I looked at the grafana data for the times where these batches of slow inits pop up and iowait is always high. Could something block the processes becuase of iowait or is iowait measuring memory access, too?

**Edit 3**: The code used for the timining (cpu time) is

```
  clock_t t = clock();

  result = g_object_newv(TYPE_VHOST_RESULT, 0, NULL);

  t = clock() - t; // stop

  ap_log_error(APLOG_MARK, APLOG_ERR, 0, r->server, "%i %s result init clock %f ms", thepid, r->hostname, ((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC*1000);
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: IMHO, you may need to improve your profiling. `gettimeofday` is wall time. So if your process is switched out between calls of `gettimeofday` then the calculated time will not be accurate. One suggestion is to use `clock` instead - just to eliminate that as a factor.

Comment: @kaylum but with clock I would get the CPU time, not the time that elapsed for the caller / user, right? I want to measure and improve the time for the user, not the CPU time.

Comment: Yes of course the end goal is to improve the time for the user. But to get there you need to have the right data. You have come to the conclusion that `g_object_new` is taking 500ms sometimes. But that conclusion may not be correct and hence you would be looking in totally the wrong place. That's why you need CPU time so that you can say confidently, yes, this call *alone* took all that time.

Comment: I used clock() too (`clock() - t_start / CLOCKS_PER_SECOND`) and it gives me plain zero.

Comment: Please show the *exact and full* code that you tried for `clock`. For starters, the snippet you have shown does not look right as it appears to be missing parentheses around the subtraction.

Comment: I used `((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC*1000` (to get milliseconds). t is `t = clock() - t;` after initialized with `clock_t t = clock();`

Comment: Please, show the *exact* code. In particular, how are you printing the value? If you are printing it as an `int` (that is `%d` or equivalent) then you will get `0` if the value is less than 1ms.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks, it's in edit 3.

Comment: Knowing what `TYPE_VHOST_RESULT` does during the initialization phase would help too.

Answer (score 1):

+1 to use clock() or even better clock_getttime().

In addition, if you instantiate object with no parameters you can avoid the varargs overhead by using:

```
g_object_newv(TYPE_VHOST_RESULT, 0, NULL);
```

If you see spikes form time to time, one explanation could be the memory subsystem. A (hidden) free() call will cause glibc to consolidate free regions from time to time.